# How to store unlimited pictures and videos for free without losing original quality?

Tags: video, backup, photography, cloud-storage

My goal is to have unlimited Photo and Video storage with priority being

1. Ease of management
2. $Free$ (excluding local hardware if necessary).
3. Resiliency of "high quality" photo and video
4. Resiliency of original (highest) quality photo and video.

Note: #4 is called out separately, because I don't believe there is currently a free, unlimited quantity/quality cloud solution for photos and videos. Although I don't want to lose #4, it wouldn't be detrimental as long as I had #3.

- Must support storing photos/videos from Android, IOS, and Windows. Photos/videos from other dumb sources (Camera, GoPro, Scanner, etc.), which I would assume would be by dropping in a folder on Windows. Would be nice if the solution worked for Mac and/or Linux.
  Must support family of users. Bonus if can consider each users privacy.
- Must have at least 3 copies not including copies on mobile devices. For example: (Cloud + Local + Local Backup) or (CloudVendorA + CloudVendorB + Local).
- Should be clear when something is wrong (e.g. 3 copies of X do not exist)
- Should be able to rename files without making copies.
- Should be able to control backup over cellular, wifi, and local network.
- Should not have to physically connect mobile devices.
- Would be nice to control what stays local on device. All devices will not be able to store the entire library due to size constraints.
- Would be nice to be able to edit/tag metadata on the file across all 3 copies.

Answer (score 2):

Partial solution:

**Google Photos** will back up unlimited quantity photos and videos with a cap on quality:

> Back up unlimited photos and videos for free, up to 16MP and 1080p HD.
>   Access them from any phone, tablet, or computer on photos.google.com –
>   your photos will be safe, secure, and always with you.

**Amazon Photos**: If you have Amazon Prime, Amazon Photos will back up unlimited quantity of photos with no cap on quality, but will not store videos for free. *Personally, I consider this **free** because I will always have Prime for all the other benefits (shipping, music, video, etc.)*

Possible further solutions. Need to work out orchestration.

- Need Phone to PC auto transfer of high quality video
- Use Google Sync and Photos windows app to transfer photos to PC.
- Use Amazon Photos windows app to transfer high quality photos to PC.
- Use PC Backup software or sync software to backup folder(s). Could also benefit from versioning (no auto deletes) to save from user error or cloud error.

Comment: Google Photos doesn't really store original-quality photos under the "High" quality setting. Even for those photos under 16 MP, they are lossily compressed somewhat.